# How does the tar flag --totals interact with the -z flag?

Tags: tar, gzip

> **-z, --gzip**
>   filter the archive through gzip
>
> **--totals[=SIGNAL]**
>   print total bytes after processing the archive; with an argument - print total bytes when this SIGNAL is delivered;
>   Allowed signals are: SIGHUP, SIGQUIT, SIGINT, SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2; the
>   names without SIG prefix are also accepted

Consider for example the command from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1331502/291007):

```
tar --totals=USR1 -czf output.tar input.file
Total bytes written: 6005319680 (5.6GiB, 23MiB/s)
```

Does this print the total bytes before or after passing them to `gzip`?

"bytes written" implies that it's the number of bytes written to disk, but I have currently a running job where tar claims double the number of bytes written than the target destination `tar.gz` file is taking up according to `ls -lah`.
Hence, I assume that it is actually "bytes that would have been written" but I cannot find documentation on that behaviour.

I am running `tar (GNU tar) 1.27.1`.